# Displaying Scale Degrees

Tags: discussion

Often in answers, I will find myself repeatedly writing a phrase like "the 7th scale degree". But there is a music theory shorthand notation for scale degrees: the number of the scale degree with a caret/hat/circumflex symbol above it.

What we can do currently (for example, with 7):

- Type out: "7th scale degree"
- Place a caret after the number: 7^ -- which looks awkward, and looks like an exponentiation symbol.
- Use `&circ;` after the digit: 7ˆ, which is arguably slightly better than the caret.

Is there any way to combine the digit and the circumflex? After all, we have html entities for typesetting accidentals (♯, ♭, ♮), so why not scale degrees? At the very least, if we can't mimic the hat-notation in the literature, should we create our own community standard for notating scale degrees?

OTOH, would it even be desirable to have such a notation? It is used in Shenkerian analysis, at least, but I'm not sure how widespread its use is outside of that. Certainly beginners to this site would not know what it means.

**Edit:** Another possibility is using a combining circumflex, as Matthew Read suggests. Here is a screenshot of what that looks like in a freshly-updated-Chrome on my Windows 7 system:

[image]

It is similarly off-center in Firefox and IE, as well as Chrome on my android phone. I also experimented (in a trial post that I never submitted) with typing the circumflex after all seven digits -- which is similarly off-centered, but on the other side -- and with using other [Combining Diacritics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks). The majority were similarly off-centered, especially those that are located above the main character.

Comment: I just want to note, I've never seen this notation before. There's a disclaimer on that which is the last time I studied music theory in an academic setting was 1996. I have music theory books around but they are all from the mid-90s and earlier, so if this is recent notation I wouldn't have seen it anyway.

Comment: I would love to see functionality where this was possible. For what it's worth, my experience tells me that in academic texts (pre-publication), authors typically use the form ^7 with the circumflex before the integer. It would be great if something like `&7;` could result in a proper scale-degree caret above the given integer.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a *combining* circumflex accent, so it gets applied to the character:

`&#770;7` turns into ̂7.

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0302/index.htm

Comment: Meh... that feels like its what I should be doing, but it doesn't really look any better. It's still not above the number like it should be, although I've read that its appearance is browser- and font-dependent.

Comment: @CalebHines Your browser must not properly support Unicode.  I'm using Chrome on Windows 8.1 and 10.

Comment: I've used Firefox, Chrome and IE on Windows 7, and also Chrome on my android phone. On all of them, the circumflex only half-ovelaps with the edge of the 7.

Comment: I've added a screenshot from Chrome to my question.

Comment: @CalebHines Maybe try following [this](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95290?hl=en) and choose UTF-8?  There's also [this](http://superuser.com/a/705563/59659), and disabling DirectWrite in `chrome://flags`.

Comment: Haven't tried the other suggestions yet, but the "UTF-8" encoding ("Unicode" in Firefox) is already selected.